# Ignore loop constant in for loop

Tags: kotlin

In Swift you can ignore the loop constant by using `_` like so:

```
for _ in 0...10 {
  //loop logic here
}
```

Is there an equivalent in Kotlin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use [repeat()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html) function:

```
repeat(10){
  //loop logic here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just use a forEach loop, and don't use `it` inside the closure:

```
(1..10).forEach {
    println("hello")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin also knows the [convention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#underscore-for-unused-variables-since-11) of naming lambda parameters `"_"` in order to indicate they are unused. The following looks very similar to your example:

```
(1..10).forEach { _ ->
  //loop logic here
}
```